# Prove that $\exists g \in SO(n)$ such that $gv_i = w_i$ for $i = 1, 2$ where all these vectors are O.N.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

> Let $n \ge 3$ and let $\pi$ be the natural representation of $SO(n)$ in $\Bbb C^n$ ( where by  $SO(n)$ I mean the real group). Let $v_1, v_2$ be a pair of orthonormal vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ and $w_1, w_2$ a second such pair.
>
> Show that $\exists g \in SO(n)$ such that $gv_i = w_i$ for $i = 1, 2$

My attempt:

So if $V= \Bbb C^n$ consists of column vectors, and since the group consists of matrices, I guess the natural representation is the one consisting in left multiplication by an element of the group?  $\pi(g)v = gv$. Now my idea is that given the orthonormality of each set of vectors, in each case they can be part of a basis of $\Bbb R^n$, but I am not sure if that is helpful and how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v_1, v_2$ can be completed to an orthonormal basis (of $\Bbb{R}^n$) $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$.  Now put the $v_i$ as column vectors in a matrix $V$.  Then $V\in O(n)$.  If $\det(V)=-1$ you can invert the sign of one of the vectors $v_3,\ldots v_n$ to get a matrix $V\in SO(n)$.  (This is where you use that $n\ge 3$).  The matrix $V$ multiplying column vectors from the left maps $e_1, e_2$ to $v_1, v_2$ respectively (where $e_i$ are the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$.)

Now repeat this process to get a matrix $W\in SO(n)$ such that $W$ multiplying column vectors on the left maps $e_1, e_2$ to $w_1, w_2$ respectively.

Finally let $g=WV^{-1}=WV^\top$.

Comment: How can I check explicitly that the matrix with the $v_i$'s as columns is orthogonal?

Comment: In n=2, wy can't I do the same trick of inverting the sign of one of the vectors?

Comment: @darkside: 1) Because orthogonality is $V^\top V=I$ which is equivalent to the columns being orthnormal.  (Similarly $V V^\top=I$ is equivalent to the rows being orthonormal.)  2) For $n=2$ you're locked into $v_1, v_2$.  You can flip the sign of the determinant by swapping them, but then the pair $v_2, v_1$ may have to map to $w_1, w_2$ by a matrix in $SO(2)$, and not $v_1, v_2$ mapping to $w_1, w_2$ as we want.